# google earth engine: how resume a specific batch who fail

Tags: batch-processing, google-earth-engine, resume-download

I'm first time using Google Earth engine via this repo:
https://github.com/kratzert/Caravan/blob/main/code/Caravan_part1_Earth_Engine.ipynb

All is working good but at a moment I forgot to dowload finished batch on my pc to free some space on google Drive.
So 2 batch has fail du to lack of memory space.

Can I just resume this 2 specific failed batchs?
Or I have to run again the code to download all batch? (7 days)?
If I run again, can I stopthe process after the number of batch missing and use the other batch of the first try??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no way to resume a task

Answer (score 2):

It's generally a good practice to chunk out larger tasks so that you can pick up where you left off / avoid mysterious fails that seem common w massive requests.

That's been my experience, anyways.

Comment: ok, I will check how to do that, thank for the info